# How to create a dropdown list with node ids?

Tags: nodes

I need to create a dropdown list box which contains the list of node ids of a specific content type. Then after selecting the node id in the dropdown i need the content of the node to be displayed below the dropdown.

Iam new to drupal. Is there any way to create the dropdown list box with the features...?

Answer (score 0):

To get all the nodes ID's for a content-type, you can use EntityFieldQuery and node_load_multiple:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'mycontenttype')
  ->execute();
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
```

If you are using [FAPI](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) (form API), you can populate your dropdown list with these values easily.

Unfortunately, I can't help with the last part (displaying the node under the form).

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of nodes of a specific type, assuming $type contains your content type, use [node_load_multiple](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7):

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type));
```

Create a select using the [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) in a custom module.